# How to rewrite this javascript that receives a request object as JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to learn how to do some AJAX (using comets) with JQuery, I have a Javascript version, am curious to see if anyone knows the JQuery equivalent.

```
 function go(){
     var url = '<%= ApplicationPathUtils.getApplicationPath(pageContext) + "/Weather" %>';
     var request =  new XMLHttpRequest();
     request.open("GET", url, true);
     request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-javascript;");
     request.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (request.readyState == 4) {
             if (request.status == 200){
                 if (request.responseText) {
                     var forecastsElement = $("forecasts"); 
                     forecastsElement.innerHTML = request.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    go();                                
                }
            };
            request.send(null);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function go() {
  var url = '<%= ApplicationPathUtils.getApplicationPath(pageContext) + "/Weather" %>';
  $('#forcasts').load(url, go);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it reusable(untested):

```
var url = '<%= ApplicationPathUtils.getApplicationPath(pageContext) + "/Weather" %>';
function go(url,selector) {
  $(selector).load(url, function(response) {
      if(response) {
          go(url,selector);
      }
  });
}

go(url,'#forcasts');
```